# Multiple Instantiatations of the Same Font

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, fonts

In the code for my GUI there are literally dozens of instances of statement sequences similar to:

```
aLabel = new JLabel("Label #1", JLabel.CENTER);
aLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", BOLD, 14));
panelOne.add(aLabel);
aLabel = new JLabel("Label #2", JLabel.CENTER);
aLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", BOLD, 14));
panelOne.add(aLabel);
```

My question: is this wasteful of resources because I’m instantiating a new `Font` object every time? Would the following method be acceptable / prefereable?

```
Font commonFont = new Font("Arial", BOLD, 14);
aLabel = new JLabel("Label #1", JLabel.CENTER);
aLabel.setFont(commonFont);
panelOne.add(aLabel);
aLabel = new JLabel("Label #2", JLabel.CENTER);
aLabel.setFont(commonFont);
panelOne.add(aLabel);
```

Thanks

Comment: *"Would the following method be acceptable / prefereable?"*  Yes.  It is more maintainable.  You might also consider tweaking the PLAF.  OTOH `Font commonFont = new Font("Arial", BOLD, 14);` would be better written as `Font commonFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, BOLD, 14);`

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is preferable to share resources like that.

If you are changing all the labels in your application you can use the UIManager to set the default Font:

```
UIManager.put("Label.font", new Font(....));
```

Now any label created after the above statement is executed will be created with your new Font.